# Transparent background for Facebook "like" button

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, transparency

I need the background for the [Facebook "like" button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) to be transparent.
I've achieved this one time but I don't remember how I did it.

`allowTransparency="true"` in the `iframe` version of the button doesn't work either.
Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the "Facebook social plugin" text?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4870082/how-to-remove-the-facebook-social-plugin-text)

Answer (score 0):

`allowTransparency="true"` with iframe version should work, I have used it recently without any problem like this:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=242000359180192&amp;href=www.facebook.com%2Fbevagus&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=180&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;locale=cs_CZ" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:180px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```